# cypress: comparing information in 2 sites

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm starting with cypress and need to compare 2 different environments.

I did a script, but is not working properly.

My goal is:

1 -  search for a specific selector value at 2 different environments.

2 -  get it's value (in both env) , and then compare it if equal.

The below comparision work, but seems very poor code and it stop in first error assert and can't query reference selector, just text.

Any help is appreciated.

```
describe('Testing Page', function() {

  //urls i need to test
  var relative_urls = [
    '/products/test1',
    '/products/test2',
  ]

  relative_urls.forEach((url) =>  {
  //each url is compared here...
  var productInfo = [];
  //here goes the environments URL.
  var testURL = 'https://www.myurl.com' + url;
  var referenceURL = 'http://test.myurl.com' + url;

  it('Comparing data from url:' + url, function() {

    cy.visit(testURL)
    //get data from selector and add it to array
    cy.get('body').find(".myselector h1").should(($input) => {
      productInfo.push($input.val())
    })
    cy.get('body').find(".myselector h2").should(($input) => {
      productInfo.push($input.val())
    })
    //requesting second url
    cy.request(referenceURL)
    .its('body').should( ($input) => {

      for (var j=0;j<productInfo.length;j++) {
      //expect works, but compares to all site, and i need to search in  a specific selector. 
      //Also, when it gets the first error, it stops and do not search all elements  of array

            expect($input.includes(productInfo[j]), 'Notice: ' + productInfo[j]).to.be.true
          }
        }
      })
   })
 })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From reading the documentation, `cy.request` is really making a plain HTTP request without doing any parsing, which means you basically have to parse the body of the response yourself. `cy.visit` will actually get the DOM elements so you can use Cypress's query syntax to navigate the page.

I think once you have the element values from the first page you should just do `cy.visit` again and parse the second page.

EDIT: Apparently you can't use `cy.visit` cross-domain. In that case, maybe you could try parsing the response body into a DOM node like this:

```
var el = document.createElement( 'html' );
el.innerHTML = request.body // you can get the request object from cy.request;
```

Then use `el.querySelector` to navigate the DOM tree using CSS syntax.

Comment: i tried to do cy.visit for different domains, but does not seems to work. https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1421

Comment: My bad, didn't see it was cross domain. I edited with an alternate solution.