# Cypress how do you export and save every single element and its content from body?

Tags: javascript, html, testing, cypress

I am trying to compare before and after contents of a webpage. I somehow need to take a snapshop of all the elements and its content of a page and then that same webpage gets upgraded via external Jenkins job. Once the job is completed, I need re-open the same webpage and ensure nothing has been changed in terms of all the contents of all the divs within body.

I've tried this but that only stores all the divs itself from the body and not their contents.

```js
var oldBody = document.createElement( 'html' );
oldBody.innerHTML = request.body 

var newBody = document.createElement( 'html' );
newBody.innerHTML = request.body 

cy.expect(oldBody).to.contain(newBody)
```

[cypress: comparing information in 2 sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57529877/cypress-comparing-information-in-2-sites)

Comment: It looks like you want to do some visual testing. Here are some options: https://docs.cypress.io/plugins/directory#Visual%20Testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you a simple snapshot of everything in a page

```js
cy.visit('http://example.com');
cy.get('html')
  .then($el => {
    cy.writeFile('./cypress/fixtures/webpage1.html', $el[0].innerHTML)
  })
```

If you just want the visible parts, `cy.get('body')` might be better as `html` gives you `<head><meta...>` tags that may change for each access.

Comment: Thanks Paolo that works great but how do I re-use that $el again within the same test in order ensure nothing has been changed (after external Jenkins job has updated it) ?

Would something like this work?
 cy.get('body')
   .then($newBody => {
 cy.readFile('./cypress/fixtures/oldBody.html',$oldData.innerHTML).eq($newBody.innerHTML)
   })

Comment: Yes that should work. If it's the same test, you can use an alias instead.

Comment: Hi Paolo, unfortunately it did not work as intended. I tried this.     
cy.get('body')
    .then($newBody => {
    cy.readFile('./cypress/fixtures/oldBody.html', $oldBody.innerHTML).should('eq', $newody.innerHTML )
    }); and I got back an error saying $oldBody is not defined so it does not know where it comes from....

Comment: I think the [cy.readFile()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/readfile#Text) is wrong, click this link for the text example (you have saved text).